# Geometric and Algebraic Multiplicity, zero dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

[image]

The eigenvalues are $\lambda =0$(because we have multiplication here), $\lambda =1$, and $\lambda =2$ for the given characteristic equation, and as (a) states, that $GM\le AM$. Now, I want to know if my reasoning is correct or not; for$\lambda =1$ the dimensions are $1$ because the power is $1$, for $\lambda =2$ the dimensions are $1, 2,$and $3$ because the power is $3$. But, for $\lambda =0$ I thought the dimensions were $0$, but it turns out they are $1$ and $2$, I understand that it has a power of $2$, but the value is zero and zero will always be zero so is the author wrong or am I wrong? And another question, why can't we have zero dimensions? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong :)

Comment: Hint: Find out
1)what is geometric multiplicity?
2)What is Eigen space?
3)What is the dimension?

Comment: i.e. non-zero, then the correct dimensions should be 1,2 for λ=0, 1 for λ=1, and 1,2,3 for λ=2; I cannot think of any other possibilities, iff the dimensions are supposed to be non-zero.

Comment: I am talking about definition of those things, which are Hinted

Comment: the algebraic should be the powers, and the geometric is the independent vectors of the the given values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An eigenspace has dimension greater than zero *by definition*. "Zero is always zero": Well yes, zero is always zero. So? When $\lambda=0$ in your example the dimension of the eigenspace is $1$ or $2$; that doesn't say zero is not zero, because the eigenvalue is not the dimension of the eigenspace.

Why is the definition that way? The definition of *eigenvalue* is this: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x\ne0$. The condition $x\ne0$ means the eigenspace cannot have dimension zero.

---

*Why* is that condition $x\ne0$ there in the definition of eigenvalue? Because if the definition were just "$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x$", allowing $x=0$, then the notion of "eigenvalue" would be totally useless and dumb, because *every* number would be an eigenvalue of *every* matrix.

Comment: That cleared my confusion, now that I understand the non-zero part. I tried it on another exercise and got the correct answer this time. Thank you, and my thanks to Chiranjeev as well!